# Regex sed issue

Tags: regex, linux, sed, makefile

My sed expression looks as belos:

```
sed -i "s/-D CONSOLELOG /-D CONSOLELOG  -fPIC /g" makefile.init
```

makefile.init

```
 CFLAGS = -std=c99 -rdynamic -g -Wall -Wno-write-strings -D CONSOLELOG
```

Output after 1st Run( As expected)

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -rdynamic -g -Wall -Wno-write-strings -D CONSOLELOG  -fPIC
```

2nd Run (Notice the extra fPIC at the end)

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -rdynamic -g -Wall -Wno-write-strings -D CONSOLELOG  -fPIC -fPIC
```

I need to modify my sed expression to get output as in (1) irrespective of the number of times it is executed

Comment: for given sample, you could add end of line anchoring..

Comment: @Sundeep: You should put it as an answer

Comment: Or with `awk`, you could do `awk '$NF=="CONSOLELOG"{$(NF+1)="-fPIC"; NF++}1'`

Comment: A simple alternative... you add a second `sed` in your script that collapses `-fPIC -fPIC` into `-fPIC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri 's/-D CONSOLELOG (-fPIC )?$/&-fPIC /' file
```

This would insert at most 2 `-fPIC` options following a `-D CONSOLELOG` option.

Answer (score 2):

Sample changed for illustration purposes

```sh
$ cat ip.txt 
42 foo baz 
ijk baz xyz
$ sed -i 's/baz $/&123/' ip.txt
$ cat ip.txt
42 foo baz 123
ijk baz xyz

$ # further runs won't change input
$ sed -i 's/baz $/&123/' ip.txt
$ cat ip.txt
42 foo baz 123
ijk baz xyz
```

- `$` is a meta character to ensure matching only at end of line
- so, matches elsewhere in the line won't be changed and hence applying the command again won't result in duplication
- `&` in replacement section is backreference to entire matched string in search section
- since there can only be one match at end of line, `g` modifier is not needed

To replace anywhere in the line(assuming only single match per line)

```sh
$ cat ip.txt 
42 foo baz 
ijk baz xyz
$ sed -i '/baz 123/! s/baz /&123/' ip.txt
$ cat ip.txt
42 foo baz 123
ijk baz 123xyz

$ # further runs won't change input
$ sed -i '/baz 123/! s/baz /&123/' ip.txt
$ cat ip.txt
42 foo baz 123
ijk baz 123xyz
```

- `sed` commands can be qualified with [addressing](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses)
- here, `/baz 123/!` means lines *not* matching `baz 123`

Further reading: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)